# Is there a spotlight-like search in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Is there a way to bring up a search box in Sublime Text that you can start typing in possible commands to see what you have installed, and what it might be mapped to?  Kind of like what OSX has?

Comment: Cmd+Alt+P? https://www.dropbox.com/s/0v7b8iubhuhvpnk/Screenshot%202015-01-31%2010.08.06.png?dl=0

Comment: Windows machine.. Window key with that combo doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, Ctrl+Shift+P. It's named "Command palette" and it's first entry in "Tools" menu (https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2ch6hfnh4n1v6c/Screenshot%202015-01-31%2010.24.21.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

Command Palette (hat tip to Tommi)

Ctrl-Shift-P (Windows)
Cmd-Alt-P (OSX)